# Update attribute on location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, attribute-table, update

How do I add a location attribute to a point file, where the location is an ID from an underlying shapefile, using ArcMap 10.1?

---

Two layers, I have polygons with a location ID, 1,2,3,4,5 etc. I have point layer which I would like to add a new column to, and update that column with the ID from the polygon file

Comment: Could you post a screenshot and/or explain a little further what information you have and how you want it?

Comment: 2 layers, I have polygones with a location ID, 1,2,3,4,5 etc. I have point layer which I would like to add a new column to, and update that column with the ID from the polygon file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided that the points and polygons overlap (or it is clear which point is closest to each polygon) you should use [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000q000000) for this analysis.

It will give you all (or specified) columns from your join features (polygons) to your target features (points). You should probably use *Join one to one* for Join Type and *Intersect* or *Within* if your points are inside the polygons, *Within a distance* if not.

Hope that helps!